# How can I access other Spotify users' currently playing tracks?

Tags: spotify

I want to build an app where a user can see what their friends are listening to.

I can get my own currently playing track by using the player model.

I can get another user's toplist by supplying a userName to the toplist model.

But how can I get another user's currently playing track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, directly.

If you want to do this, you'll need to have your own web service that keeps track of it. When a user uses your app and opts-in to having their currently playing track uploaded to your service for your friends to see. Of course, that means that everyone needs to use your app in order to keep your service populated.

Another approach will be to connect to the Facebook API and get friends' listening history that way.

Comment: Okay, was suspecting that. Hope it will be available at one point. Thanks.